# In the NumberBlock's time-travel episode "Double Back", what are all of the references to other time-travel movies (or other media)?

Tags: time-travel, mathematics

I was watching the (children's show) NumberBlock's episode "[Double Back](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tpeUFIzG_Zg)" with my two kids (5M and 2F), and I noticed several references to Back to the Future as well as a recurring reference to Groundhog Day.

Back to the Future references:

1. Clock tower getting struck by lightning.
2. Delorean-style vehicle
3. Skateboarding (might be coincidence, but given the cart I think not)

Groundhog Day recurring reference: music playing at the beginning of every time loop

Given those clear references from two different movies, I suspect there are others I'm missing. I'd love to compile a complete list, or as complete as we can make it.

Comment: I think you've spotted them all. Maybe the Ferris Bueller 'racing against time jump over the fence' bit? And the flying car reference to BTTF2, but I think that's about it...

Comment: @Valorum After watching it a few more times (it's currently one of my kids' favorites), I'm wondering about the bit with 64 having himself delivered in that box. I don't recognize it as an homage to anything, but it feels like it might be referencing something else.

Comment: It's a reference to BTTF2 where he delivers a letter to Marty in the future